# Jquery resizable bug with helper, losing 1px

Tags: jquery

There is a bug in jquery resizable with helper.
When you resize a div using only one side, the other side lose 1px.

You can test this here:
http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#helper

For example, use Element Inspector of your browser and look at metrics/layout.
Try to resize right side and you'll see the bottom side losing 1px.

Comment: I hope you've also reported this to the jQuery UI people.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer didn't solve my (same) problem. I solved it like this:

```
$(".resizable").resizable({
  helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
  start: function( event, ui ) {
    $(ui.helper).height(ui.originalSize.height);
    $(ui.helper).width(ui.originalSize.width);
 }
});
```

This forces the size of the helper in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

At the resizable init, put the start event like this.
Ps: My resizable components have a grid[5,5], so I use module(%) to validate if one of the sides have lost 1px and then, add 1px again.

```
$(".resizable").resizable({
  helper: "ui-resizable-helper"
 ,grid: [5,5]
 ,start: function( event, ui ) {
    if ((ui.size.height%5) != 0) ui.size.height += 1;
    if ((ui.size.width%5) != 0)  ui.size.width  += 1;
 }
});
```

Hope this helps you guys!!!

Comment: This doesn't work. Even if you change the value of ``ui.size``, you're not affecting the size of the helper, which ultimately sets the size of the resizable element.